# Count distinct values in a string column

Tags: powerbi, dax, distinct, powerbi-desktop

I am currently working with Excel and I need to write the DAX code for counting distinct values in a string column. The formula that I'm using in Excel is:
IF(SUMPRODUCT(($BV$2:$BV2=BV2)*($BV$2:$BV2=BV2))>1;0;1); where BV is equal to column TK.

The result that I expect is in column Distinct:

[**TK                       Distinct**
43470,yyy,uuu,20191          1
43470,yyy,uuu,20191          0
43470,yyw,uuu,20191          0
43470,yyyz,uuu,20191         0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjxiR.png)

I have tried various of codes and everything that came in my mind, but I am lacking experience in comparing values in DAX, and kinda beat at the moment.

Can someone help?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Your result abit confusing, why last two is distinct but also count as 0?

Comment: because if it is unique I put 1 while if TK is found several times, I put 0. This I need to then count how many unique strings are. Hope this helps you to understand my issue. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: sorry, you are right, the unique values should count 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replicate the `sumproduct` function in PowerBi, although the formula is quite difficult to understand, accept the answer if help :)

1. You need to create a `index column` in query editor
2. Apply the following formula then you are good to go:

   ```
    Duplicate check = IF( CALCULATE(COUNT('Sheet1 (2)'[tks]),
                    FILTER(ALL('Sheet1 (2)'),'Sheet1 (2)'[Index] <= EARLIER('Sheet1 (2)'[Index])),
                        FILTER(ALL('Sheet1 (2)'),'Sheet1 (2)'[tks]=EARLIER('Sheet1 (2)'[tks])))>1,
                            0,1)
   ```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. unfortunately I am not sufficient experienced in Power BI because the result is non what is expected. I beg your pardon but there is a way to replicate the formula IF(SUMPRODUCT(($BV$2:$BV2=BV2)*($BV$2:$BV2=BV2))>1;0;1) in power Bi so that I can insert it in a new column of my table: This would make it much easier for me to have all the filters already available. Thank you so much for your much appreciated help.

Comment: See my edited answer, the `sumproduct` function can be replicated in PowerBI :)

Comment: Welcome, if you like it :)